# Hello, I am having issues changing the order of an user story in ADO backlog

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I am having issues changing the order of an user story in ADO backlog. These stories are not in a sprint and does have Parent (Epic & feature )& child (Task, bugs, test case) links attached to it. Is there a way to change the order of all these stories in backlog?

Tried to drag & drop the stories to change the order but didn't work. Expecting to change the orders of all the stories (30) in my backlog.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the following things to see whether you have the required permissions to reorder the work items on Backlogs:

1. you need to have an access level higher than **`Stakeholder`**. The **`Stakeholder`** cannot drag-and-drop work items on Backlogs.
2. You need to have the **`Contributor`** role at least in the project.
3. Check whether the work items are owned by other teams. You can't reorder items owned by other teams.

   If a work item is owned by another team, you can see the [image]info icon appears in the first column as shown in the following image.

   [image]

For more details, you can reference the following documentations:

- [**Stakeholder access quick reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/stakeholder-access?view=azure-devops-2022#azure-boards)
- [**Organize your backlog**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/organize-backlog?view=azure-devops-2022#prerequisites)
- [**Limitations on reordering backlog items owned by other teams**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/organize-backlog?view=azure-devops-2022#limitations-on-reordering-backlog-items-owned-by-other-teams)

---

Comment: @user23260766, Is there any update from you? Have checked with the suggestions shared in my above answer? Are the suggestions helpful for you?

Comment: Also, make sure you are viewing the backlog as a flat list of items (i.e., no parents). I'm not sure why, but in a recent update, trying to reorder backlog items in a hierarchy is buggy.